# Python zlib inflate error

Tags: python, compression, zlib

I'm trying to inflate a `zlib` compressed file using Python with this code:

```
import zlib

data = open("3B42.110531.21.6A.HDF.Z", 'rb').read()
inflated = zlib.decompress(data)
f = open('3B42.110531.21.6A.HDF', 'wb')
f.write(inflated)
f.close()
```

I've already done several attempts with different options:

- Adding a second parameter to `zlib.decompress (zlib.decompress(data,-15))`
- Skipping the first two bytes `zlib.decompress(data[2:-4]) / zlib.decompress(data[2:] /.. )`
- Basecoding to 64 bits.

Anyway, I keep failing with this message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\opt\Python25\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 325, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "E:\Tesis\data\uncompress.py", line 6, in <module>
    inflated = zlib.decompress(data)
error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

The only difference is using a negative parameter in `zlib.decompress`: invalid block type.

```
import zlib

data = open("3B42.110531.21.6A.HDF.Z", 'rb').read()
inflated = zlib.decompress(data,-15)
f = open('3B42.110531.21.6A.HDF', 'wb')
f.write(inflated)
f.close()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\opt\Python25\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 325, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "E:\Tesis\data\uncompress.py", line 6, in <module>
    inflated = zlib.decompress(data,-15)
error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid block type
```

I'm sure that the file is not corrupted, I can open it from WinRAR.
(environment: Windows x64, Python 2.5, I guess that the file is in a Unix machine..binary downloaded)

I've already read the following links

- [zlib-decompression-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316357/zlib-decompression-in-python)
- [python-inflate and deflate-implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089662/python-inflate-and-deflate-implementations)

Comment: What does [`file(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) say the file is?  Is it "gzip compressed data"?

Comment: No. It's a unix compressed file.

Answer (score 2):

`.Z` indicates a [**LZC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compress)/[`compress`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/compress) file. Despite the name similarity, this compression format differs from **gzip**, which is what [zlib](http://zlib.net/) implements.

Try using the command-line [`compress`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/compress) utility to uncompress the file (Your `gzip` program may also be able to decompress it).

Comment: Just to add some clarification: zlib (the library) implements DEFLATE (the data format) as defined in RFC 1951, *and* gzip (RFC 1952), which is a wrapper around DEFLATE. There's also zlib the data format (RFC 1950), which is also a DEFLATE container. zlib the library *also* implements zlib the data format. Confused yet? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The file extension '.Z' and the attempts you tried so far sound like you either use zLib wrong (but it seems correct according to your posted links) or the zLib stream isn't right at the beginning of the file.

You can use my tool [Precomp](http://schnaader.info/precomp.php) with the file to detect the position of zLib stream(s) inside the file:

```
precomp -v -slow 3B42.110531.21.6A.HDF.Z
```

It should output something like this:

```
Possible zLib-Stream (slow mode) found at position 85, windowbits = 15
Can be decompressed to 9264 bytes
```

This will tell you both the position of the stream and the windowbits parameter to use (negated).

It will also tell you if there are zLib streams inside the file at all because as [phihag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864258/python-zlib-inflate-error/6864366#6864366) said, it's possible that the file is compressed with something different than deflate/zLib. Note that in this case, there'll probably be some misdetections as the zLib header is only 2 bytes in size, but those can be identified by decompressing to <100 bytes.

Comment: Possible zLib-Stream (slow mode) found at position 4524, windowbits = 13
Can be decompressed to 3 bytes
Less than 32 bytes, skipping.
Possible zLib-Stream (slow mode) found at position 11760, windowbits = 12
Can be decompressed to 9 bytes
Less than 32 bytes, skipping.
Possible zLib-Stream (slow mode) found at position 21507, windowbits = 9

Comment: Sorry, thanks in advance for your help.. I downloaded precomp, but when I see windowbits, It varies from 9, 13, 8, 12 and 15... I don´t have a clue really of what it means... (log is over this comment, I accidentally pressed Enter before ending the comment..)

Comment: This looks like the misdetection I mentioned, so this file indeed has no deflate/zLib streams in it and can't be decompressed using zLib. You should accept phihag's answer and look for a tool/library to decompress LZC/compress.